# Quote for set up and on-going

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

We are a charity interested in CRM and I wondered if you could please provide me with some information:

1. A brief outline of what is on offer with your CRM package
2. How we could use it – the benefits
3. How much it would cost (initial set up and on-going)
4. Any difficulties in implementing the system

Many thanks,

Alice

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM is indeed a good CRM for most charities in my experience :-)

There is actually no such thing as `your CRM package`. CiviCRM is community based and open source, and getting started works in a different way.
There is no sales organization in CiviCRM itself, the software is community developed and based. Most people answering posts here are CiviCRM users and/or experts answering questions as community members in their own time, like me.

As there is no license cost involved, there is also nothing (and everything) `on offer`.

Your best first step to get your questions answered would be to contact a CiviCRM partner that is close to you. You can find a list [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors). One of the partners will be able to help you with some of your questions.

A brief outline of what is on offer can be found in the [User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/). That might help you to get an idea. I would strongly recommend you to outline what you would want to achieve though, rather than focus on what is *on offer*.

As far as the costs go, please check this [similar post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-much-does-it-cost).

Good luck setting the first steps!

Answer (score 4):

The best place to start would probably be some of the case studies here: https://civicrm.org/case-studies

And then try contacting a few of the partners near to you: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

CiviCRM is used by a lot of charities and non-profit organisations. It also has a large number of extensions so can usually support your use-cases.  Without understanding your requirements a little better it is difficult to offer more advice.